# Struggling to understand 'Zero-Page Indirect Address Indexed by Y' for the 6502 Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, memory-address, addressing-mode, 6502, zero-page

This is specifically for the **NES** console which uses a slightly modified **8-bit 6502** microprocessor. Below follows the code with my comments explaining what each line does as far as my basic understanding goes (please let me know if I misunderstood any lines):

```
lda #$00   ; Load the accumulator (A register) with the immediate value 0x00
sta $02    ; Store the value in the accumulator into memory address $02

lda #$03   ; Load the accumulator with the immediate value 0x03
sta $03    ; Store the value in the accumulator into memory address $03

lda #$14   ; Load the accumulator with the immediate value 0x14
sta $0302  ; Store the value in the accumulator into memory address $0302

clc        ; Clear the carry flag (CLC instruction)
lda #$10   ; Load the accumulator with the immediate value 0x10
ldy #$02   ; Load the Y register with the immediate value 0x02

adc ($02),y
```

It seems like, before the final line `adc ($02)`, the status of memory addresses and registers is as follows:

- `$02` = `0x00`
- `$03` = `0x03`
- `$0302` = `0x14`
- `A` = `0x10`
- `Y` = `0x02`

Therefore, the final line to me seems to indicate the following:

1. `$02` + `Y`
2. `0x00` + `0x02`
3. `0x02` with the value stored at this address being `0x00`
4. Now we add `0x00` to A register which is simply `0x10` but apparently the results should be is follows, thus I am a bit confused where I made a mistake:

`A=$24 X=$00 Y=$02`

Some additional notes, supposedly the following is true:

*The value in memory locations $02 and $03 was previously set to specify the address $0300.*

When does this happen? I specifically struggle to understand this line. Are they both specified to address `$0300`?

Comment: The fact that `$02 = 0x00` and `$03 = 0x03` means the 16 bit pointer at `$02/$03` is in fact `0x0300`. The addressing mode `($02),Y` fetches that pointer then adds the value in `Y` which is how you get `$0302` where the value `0x14` has been previously stored. That will be added to `A`.

Comment: The point perhaps worth emphasizing is that ($02) specifies the start address of a 16-bit pointer, and the 6502 is "little endian", which means the low byte of the address is specified: $02 which has 0x00. The high byte of the pointer is read from $02 + 1 = $03, which has 0x03. Those bytes are loaded to form the pointer $0300, then Y is added to make the final address $0302.

Comment: @NickWestgate What determines when a 16-bit pointer is being used instead of just 8-bit?

Comment: @Dainank: The parentheses always indicate a 16-bit pointer. There are only three 6502 addressing modes that use this slightly confusing "indirect" syntax. 1: (absolute) 2: (zero page,X) 3: (zero page),Y ... and in each case the 16-bit pointer is stored as two bytes. low-byte at the given address, high byte at the given address + 1.

Comment: @Dainank: In reality, all pointers must be 16-bit, but often the opcode implies part of the pointer. Obviously STA $0200 has a 16-bit pointer, and STA $02 has an 8-bit pointer with an implied upper byte of zero, so $0002. You can also write STA $0002, but that instruction is 3 bytes vs 2. Other CPUs (eg x86, ARM etc) have more flexibility with operation and operands being independent, but 6502 is much simpler. The opcode defines the required operands, and there is a fixed set of combinations of operation and addressing modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adc ($02),y` is an example of indirect indexed addressing. The parenthesis around `$02` means that `$02` does not contain the operand but `$02` and `$03` together contain a 16 bit address that, when added to `y` contains the operand.

This is the sequence of what happens with `adc ($02),y`

1. The CPU loads the number at the address `$02` which is `$00`.
2. The CPU loads the address at `$03` which is `$03`.
3. The CPU forms a 16 bit number from the two loads it has done. The 6502 is little endian, so the number at the low address becomes the low byte. We end up with `$0300`. This is sometimes called the base address
4. The CPU adds `y` to the base address to get `$0302`. This new number is used as the address in which to find the operand.
5. The CPU loads the byte at `$0302` which is `$14` and adds it to the accumulator.